# Generate data based on a distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an array with values

data = [1,2,3,4,5]

I want to generate a sample of 20000 entries such that it follows a trend of number alongside time such that intially there are 5 available and it decreases with time to 1.

I was trying to achieve this by :

```
def random_iti(start, end, starting_prob = 1.0, ending_prob = 0.1, num_samples = 20000):

    start = start
    end = end

    # Get days between `start` and `end`
    num = (end - start)

    linear_probabilities = expon.cdf(np.linspace(starting_prob, ending_prob, num), scale = 0.3)

    # normalize probabilities so they add up to 1
    linear_probabilities /= np.sum(linear_probabilities)

    rand_days = np.random.choice(num, size = num_samples, replace = True,
             p = linear_probabilities)

    rand =  [(start + int(rand_days))]

    # return list of date strings
    return rand


num_iti = random_iti(1, 5, starting_prob = 1.0, ending_prob = 0.1, num_samples=sample_count)
```

However, running this code is giving me :

> TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Can anyone advice on what is wrong here and what needs to be done to achieve the same.

Comment: "I want to generate a sample of 20000 entries such that it follows a trend of number alongside time such that intially there are 5 available and it decreases with time to 1. " Sorry, *what*? I don't think I understand. You want that... near the beginning of the array, `1` is much more likely than `5`, but near the end, all the values are equally likely? Or just what?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, you understood correctly, with a minor change, near the begigning 5 is expected more than 1.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you will need to loop and make each random choice separately; `np.random.choice` will use the same weights for each sample regardless.

At any rate, the error happens because `rand_days` is an array of 20000 values; calling `int` on that doesn't make sense. Casting the entire array is done using the `.astype` method - but they *should already be ints*, because they are sampled from `np.arange(num)`. (By the way: this is *also* a bug - we have `start = 1` and `end = 5`, so `num = 4` - which means the possible values will be `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and **not** `4`.)

The conversion you wanted here `rand = [(start + int(rand_days))]` is instead simply: `rand = start + rand_days`. But we can make this cleaner instead: rather than passing a number as the first argument for `np.random.choice`, pass the actual sample set instead: `np.arange(start, end+1)` (since, again, ranges do not include the second endpoint). Or instead of passing `start` and `end` parameters, pass that range in directly and use it directly in the function - that gives you more customization, so you can sample from whatever data set you like.